# Vim match all characters except at start of string

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using the vim `substitute` function in a vim script, and I want to substitute all characters *after* the first initial brackets. For example, say I have a string that looks like this:

```
]]]] foo ] bar ] baz
```

I want to delete everything after the close brackets. How can I match this? Note that I want to delete close brackets *after* the initial ones, but not the ones at the beginning of the string. After the execution, the line should only be the four brackets:

```
]]]]
```

Comment: what would be the result of the given example? I didn't understand your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
:echo substitute("]]]] foo ] bar ] baz",'\(^]\+\).*','\1','g')
```

here, it echos `]]]]`.

Comment: Only one problem: it doesn't work if there are no brackets at the beginning of the string. In that case, it should yield an empty string.

Comment: @JakeKing I wrote that line for your example in question. you could change `\+` into `*`, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This `ex` expression should work:

<strike>:%s/^]+\s*//</strike>

```
:%s/\(^\]*\).*/\1/
```

Comment: That's the inverse of what I want. I want to delete everything *except* the close brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can match all closing brackets at the beginning of the string until the white space using

```
(^[]]*\s).+$
```

replace with `$1` (in vim probably `\1`)

Comment: I want to match any number of close brackets, including 0.

Comment: Read my comment on the other answer. I want to delete everything *else* not the brackets themselves.

Comment: @JakeKing can't you replace the whole string with the mach?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that could work. Though I'd still be interested if this is possible.